# TypeScript(Angular) Datetime To Date

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I got this error message

> The specified value "2019-04-13T00:00:00" does not conform to the
>   required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

I want to change the date / time to a date.

datetime example:2019-04-13T00:00:00

I want to do example:2019-04-13

HTML

```
 <input
  class="form-control mr-sm-2"
  id="dates"
  name="achievement_date"
  [(ngModel)]="addItems.achievement_date"
  required
  type="date"
  placeholder="Tournament Date"
/>
```

Answer (score 12):

The first solution provided is great, as it solves your solution with Vanilla JavaScript!

However, I have two other alternative solutions.

1) This makes use of Angular's built-in [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe). You can even pass in a variety of DateTime formats.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
.
.
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {   

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this.addItems.achievement_date = datePipe.transform('2019-04-13T00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    // console.log(this.date)
  }

}
```

Do remember to import DatePipe to your providers in your module that is using it.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
.
.
@NgModule({
  .
  .,
  providers: [
    DatePipe
  ]
})
```

The above should display the dates on the input field.
I have made a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-format-pipe-gmxjif?file=app/app.component.ts) using the above solution

2) [formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate). Do take note that this may not work on the earlier versions of Angular. So far, I have only tried and tested it on Angular 7.

```
import {formatDate } from '@angular/common';
.
.
export class AppComponent  {

  date = undefined;

  constructor() {
   this.date = formatDate('2019-04-13T00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US');
  }

}
```

here is another [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-sqmhcf?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for you.

Answer (score 2):

this utility function my help

```
export const getDate = function (date: any): Date {
  const _date = new Date(date);
  return new Date(
    Date.UTC(_date.getFullYear(), _date.getMonth(), _date.getDate())
  );
};
```

or another way to return the string value base on format *'yyyy-MM-dd'*

```
export const getDate = function (date: any): string{
  const _date = new Date(date);
  return `${_date.getFullYear()}-${_date.getMonth()}-${_date.getDate()}`;      
};
```

before you save the date just clean up the value

```
this.addItems.achievement_date = getDate(this.addItems.achievement_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do store the value in a variable and then using datepipe transform covert it into desired format

```
this.StopDate= this.MachineryForm.controls.StoppageDate.value

this.StopDate = this.datepipe.transform(this.StopDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```